# How to track java servlet request using Google Analytics

Tags: java, servlets, google-analytics-api

I have a common link `http://www.mydomain.com/clickServlet` on various third party client pages with different parameter values (`http://www.mydomain.com/clickServlet?ID=123&A=123&B=123`). The link is of a java servlet. Based on the parameter values the request is redirected to an external domain.

I want to track this at java servlet level. Since i do not have access to client pages (pages where my link resides) and redirected domains, i have to setup tracking in java servlet which should record all details like `referer`, `ip`, `location`, `user-agent` etc. all the stuff which GA records. I need a solution like wherein I pass the java `HttpServletRequest` object along with GA account details and GA would record all the details from the request object.

Is this possible in Google Analytics API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google released an official API to send data to Google Analytics now. This is the [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/). This is probably the safest solution because it is an "official" and documented API.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try [JGoogleAnalytics](http://code.google.com/p/jgoogleanalytics/) library a try. It can track *usage information on Java applications through Google analytics. It can be used for gathering usage statistics on utilities, plugins(Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans etc.), client-side, server-side, middleware, desktop or any Java based applications. Hence, allowing us to perform usage & trend analysis on the application of interest.*

Comment: I have seen JGoogleAnalytics, but that is more of tracking an application events/screen etc. I need what GA javascript does to track referer, ip, location, user-agent, browser, OS etc. on server side.